# My implementation of a linear probing hashmap in C is leaking memory in the resize function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, hashmap

## Problem

I am implementing a simple linear probing hashmap in C and when running some tests I am noticing that some memory is being leaked only when the `resize_hash_map` function is called during the `hash_map_add` process.

I have referenced this book for the implementation of this hashmap: https://opendatastructures.org/

---

## Environment

I am compiling using the gcc compiler with the following flags `-std=c17 -Wall -g` for the MacOS aarch64 architecture (Apple Silicon).

---

## HashMap Implementation

The code for the HashMap implementation is as follows:

**hash_map.h**

```c
#ifndef TERRACRAFT_HASH_MAP_H
#define TERRACRAFT_HASH_MAP_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef NDEL
#define NDEL ((void*) 1)  // void pointer del tag
#endif

typedef struct HashMap HashMap;

struct HashMap {
    void** items; // pointer to array of pointers to items
    char** keys; // pointer to array of strings
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long non_null;
    unsigned long capacity;
};

HashMap* create_hash_map(unsigned long capacity);
void destroy_hash_map(HashMap* map);
void resize_hash_map(HashMap* map);
void* hash_map_get(HashMap* map, char* key);
bool hash_map_add(HashMap* map, char* key, void* item);

// TODO remove function

#endif //TERRACRAFT_HASH_MAP_H
```

**hash_map.c**

```c
#include "collections/hash_map.h"

// based on public domain implementation from: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
// note: static here limits this function to this file only
static unsigned long sdbm_hashcode(const char* str) {
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = *str++)) hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}

HashMap* create_hash_map(unsigned long capacity) {
    size_t val_bytes = sizeof(void*) * capacity;
    size_t key_bytes = sizeof(char*) * capacity;
    // create and zero arrays
    void** items = malloc(val_bytes);
    memset(items, NULL, val_bytes);

    char** keys = malloc(key_bytes);
    memset(keys, NULL, key_bytes);

    HashMap* map = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    map->items = items;
    map->keys = keys;
    map->size = 0;
    map->non_null = 0;
    map->capacity = capacity;

    return map;
}

void destroy_hash_map(HashMap* map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
        if (map->items[i] != NULL) {
            free(map->items[i]);
        }

        if (map->keys[i] != NULL) {
            free(map->keys[i]);
        }
    }

    free(map->items);
    free(map->keys);
    free(map);

    map = NULL;
}

void resize_hash_map(HashMap* map) {
    printf("resizing hash map\n");
    // TODO: this may be leaking memory

    // smallest non-negative integer d, where 2d ≥ 3n
    // we maintain this invariant to support hash functions that only work on table sizes that are a power of 2
    unsigned long d = 1;

    // bit shift d to go through the base 2 powers: 2^d until we find a value where 2^d >= 3n
    // the bit shift is an efficient way to do base 2 powers.
    while ((1<<d) < 3*map->capacity) d++;

    unsigned long new_len = (1<<d);

    // create and zero new arrays
    size_t item_bytes = sizeof(void*) * new_len;
    size_t key_bytes = sizeof(char*) * new_len;
    void** new_item_arr = malloc(item_bytes);
    memset(new_item_arr, NULL, item_bytes);

    char** new_key_arr = malloc(key_bytes);
    memset(new_key_arr, NULL, key_bytes);

    map->size = map->capacity;
    map->non_null = map->size;

    // copy old arrays to new array
    for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
        if (map->keys[i] == NULL || map->keys[i] == NDEL) continue;

        unsigned long k = sdbm_hashcode(map->keys[i]) % new_len;

        // linearly prob from position k
        while (new_key_arr[k] != NULL) k = (k == new_len-1) ? 0 : k + 1; // increment with wrap around

        new_key_arr[k] = map->keys[i];
        new_item_arr[k] = map->items[i];
    }

    // free pointers to old arrays but not their contents since the contents were moved to the new array
    free(map->keys);
    free(map->items);

    // set new arrays
    map->keys = new_key_arr;
    map->items = new_item_arr;

    // set new capacity
    map->capacity = new_len;
}

void* hash_map_get(HashMap* map, char* key) {
    unsigned long hash = sdbm_hashcode(key) % map->capacity;

    // linear probe to check for key
    while(map->keys[hash] != NULL) {
        // check if the key was found
        if (map->keys[hash] != NDEL && strcmp(map->keys[hash], key) == 0) {
            return map->items[hash];
        }
        hash = (hash == map->capacity-1) ? 0 : hash + 1;
    }

    // key not in table, return nothing
    return NULL;
}

bool hash_map_add(HashMap* map, char* key, void* item) {
    void* existing_item = hash_map_get(map, key);
    if (existing_item != NULL && existing_item != NDEL) return false;
    if (2*(map->non_null+1) > map->capacity) resize_hash_map(map); // allow for a maximum of 50% occupancy
    unsigned long hash = sdbm_hashcode(key) % map->capacity;

    // linear probe to insert
    while (map->keys[hash] != NULL && map->keys[hash] != NDEL) hash = (hash == map->capacity-1) ? 0 : hash + 1;

    if (map->keys[hash] == NULL) map->non_null++;
    map->size++;

    // create memory for string and copy key to that block of memory
    size_t key_len = strlen(key);
    map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(map->keys[hash], key, key_len+1);
    map->keys[hash][key_len] = '\0';  // strncpy does not copy terminator,  manually add it

    // set the item
    map->items[hash] = item;

    return true;
}
```

---

## Checking for leaks

Using the following driving program, I checked for leaks using the MacOS `leaks` command:
**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "collections/hash_map.h"

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} Point;

void print_point(Point* point) {
    printf("Point: (%d, %d)\n", point->x, point->y);
}

int main() {
    HashMap* map = create_hash_map(2);
    Point* one = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    one->x = 1;
    one->y = 2;

    Point* two = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    two->x = 3;
    two->y = 4;

    hash_map_add(map, "one", one);
  
    /*
     * Note:
     * When adding an item that will cause the hash map to resize, a memory leak is introduced.
     */
    hash_map_add(map, "two", two);

    Point* one_result = hash_map_get(map, "one");
    print_point(one_result);
    
    Point* two_result = hash_map_get(map, "two");
    print_point(two_result);

    destroy_hash_map(map);

    // wait for user input, gives me time to run the MacOS 'leaks' command on the executable
    // Is there a better way besides running valgrind on a linux vm? I'm on an Apple silicon mac.
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I run the executable and then while that is waiting for user input, I run the 'leaks' command as follows: `leaks terracraft` (note: terracraft is the name of the executable).

The expected report is that there are 0 leaks, however, the program (leaks) indicates that my running executable has 2 leaks.

### leaks output

The output of running the `leaks` command is:

```
Process 64507 is not debuggable. Due to security restrictions, leaks can only show or save contents of readonly memory of restricted processes.

Process:         terracraft [64507]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/terracraft
Load Address:    0x1027bc000
Identifier:      terracraft
Version:         ???
Code Type:       ARM64
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  clion [62506]

Date/Time:       2023-02-10 09:09:51.751 -0400
Launch Time:     2023-02-10 09:09:44.092 -0400
OS Version:      macOS 12.6.3 (21G419)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/leaks

Physical footprint:         1617K
Physical footprint (peak):  1617K
----

leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 64507: 1059 nodes malloced for 92 KB
Process 64507: 2 leaks for 32 total leaked bytes.

    2 (32 bytes) << TOTAL >>
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x600001120180 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x6000011201c0 [16]
```

---

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: OT: `memset(items, NULL, val_bytes);` => `memset(items, 0, val_bytes);`. `NULL` is only for pointers. Read the compiler warnings.

Comment: `map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char)); strncpy(map->keys[hash], key, key_len+1);` causes a buffer overflow. You need `+1` on the allocation. https://godbolt.org/z/b6MzqK8qf Once that is fixed along with swapping NULL for 0 the warnings are more manageable and you can see the leaks using AddressSanitizer. https://godbolt.org/z/Gbv19rhe6

Comment: OT2: in addition to Retired Ninja's comment: it's pointless to use `strncpy` (which is in no way the somewhat safer version of `strcpy`). You know that the destination buffer is large enough, therefore you can just use `strcpy`. You should simply have this: `map->keys[hash] = MALLOC(key_len + 1);  strcpy(map->keys[hash], key);`. But this is not the primary cause of the memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip :)
Now to figure out what is leaking...

Edit: also no more compiler warnings :D

Comment: Easy fix: `one` and `two` are not freed. Now there are only the leaks from `map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char) + 1);` that you need to find. Easy fix: `one` and `two` are not freed. Now there are only the leaks from `map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char) + 1);` that you need to find. https://godbolt.org/z/Edcax77aM

Comment: I don't have much familiarity with the `leaks` tool, but is there not a way to make it tell you where the leaked memory was allocated?  Valgrind can do that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as per https://godbolt.org/z/Edcax77aM, the leaked memory is definitely allocated here: `map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * ...`.

Comment: Whats the purpose of *NDEL* and *not\_null*? The latter is initialized to the number of elements, then it's incremented when a *NULL* key is encountered.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not sure, I am fairly new to MacOS development and the leaks tool is new to me too.

Comment: @CristiFati NDEL is a tag indicating a difference between a NULL space and an allocated but deleted (**not** freed) space. My implementation of this, particularly where NDEL expands to (void*)1,  is likely not the best. Also I have yet to implement the remove function, where the use of NDEL will become more clear. I am referencing this book for implementation: https://opendatastructures.org/

Comment: When you get around to setting pointers to `NDEL`, don't forget to check for it in `destroy_hash_map()` because you don't want to free `NDEL`!

Comment: I see why you would want `NDEL` in the `keys` array (so you can skip it during the linear search), for the `items` array `NULL` would be better. I.e. when removing a key/value pair (and freeing `keys[hash]` and `items[hash]`), set `keys[hash]` to `NDEL` and `items[hash]` to `NULL`. Then the test `if (existing_item != NULL && existing_item != NDEL)` can be simplified to `if (existing_item != NULL)` in `hash_map_add()`. (I think that matches the pseudo-code in your reference book.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are errors in both `resize_hash_map()` and `destroy_hash_map()`, but the memory leak is in `destroy_hash_map()`.

The main error in `resize_hash_map()` is here:

```
    map->size = map->capacity;
    map->non_null = map->size;

    // copy old arrays to new array
    for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
```

It should not be changing `map->size` and `map->non_null`. Remove those lines and change the loop termination condition to `i < map->capacity`. The above code becomes:

```
    // copy old arrays to new array
    for (int i = 0; i < map->capacity; i++) {
```

The main error in `destroy_hash_map()` is that it is using an incorrect loop termination condition:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
```

Rather than checking `i < map->size`, it should be checking `i < map->capacity`, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < map->capacity; i++) {
```

There is also a buffer overflow in `hash_map_add()` because the nemory allocated to hold the key string is not large enough to hold the null terminator:

```
    // create memory for string and copy key to that block of memory
    size_t key_len = strlen(key);
    map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(map->keys[hash], key, key_len+1);
    map->keys[hash][key_len] = '\0';  // strncpy does not copy terminator,  manually add it
```

The above code should be changed to something like this:

```
    // create memory for string and copy key to that block of memory
    size_t key_len = strlen(key);
    map->keys[hash] = malloc((key_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(map->keys[hash], key);
```

(Note: the `* sizeof(char)` part can be omitted because `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.)

Another problem is the use of `NULL` as the second argument in the calls to `memset()`.  `NULL` might be defined to expand to a integer constant of value 0, but it is more likely to be defined as such a constant converted to `void *`. That would lead to compiler warnings about conversions from pointers to integers. `NULL` is intended to be used for setting pointers to null pointer values or for comparing pointer values to null pointer values. Change the second argument of the `memset()` calls from `NULL` to `0` for portability.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the in-depth explanation and examination of my code and how to address the memory leaks :)

Answer (score 3):

### Minor issues

#### Insufficient allocation

This ...

> ```
>     // create memory for string and copy key to that block of memory
>     size_t key_len = strlen(key);
>     map->keys[hash] = malloc(key_len * sizeof(char));
> ```

... allocates insufficient space for a copy of the given key.  You also need to provide for the string terminator, too.

#### `strncpy` is not your friend

The `strncpy()` function is suited only to a certain few rather special purposes.  Generally, you should avoid it.  Often, as here, you don't need it anyway.  Where you do want a bounded copy, `strncat()` can do that -- just prime the destination by writing a string terminator in the first position.

Continuing on from the previous code, this ...

> ```
>     strncpy(map->keys[hash], key, key_len+1);
> ```

... overruns the bounds of the (too-small) allocated space.  Note well that `strncpy()` does not save you from that, because you tell it that the space is larger than it actually is.

For the particular case of making a dynamically-allocated copy of a string, you can probably save yourself effort and trouble by using `strdup()` to achieve that in one call, with no need to manually compute any sizes.  Note well that even though there is not then an explicit `malloc()`, you are responsible for `free()`ing the result when you no longer need it.  Note also, that `strdup()` is specified by POSIX, but not by the C language specification.  I'm pretty sure your implementation provides it, but if you need broad portability then relying on `strdup()` complicates that.

#### Non-idiomatic code

This ...

> ```
>         hash = (hash == map->capacity-1) ? 0 : hash + 1;
> ```

... seems correct, but it's harder to read and understand than this equivalent:

```
        hash = (hash + 1) % map->capacity;
```

#### Null pointer representation

This ...

> ```
>     // create and zero arrays
>     void** items = malloc(val_bytes);
>     memset(items, NULL, val_bytes);
> ```

... has at least two problems:

1. The second argument to `memset` should be an `int`, and although `NULL` could be an `int` in your implementation, it is more likely a `void *`.  The language spec provides for explicit pointer-to-integer conversions, but not for implicit ones.  When you mean the integer 0, write 0.
2. C does not require that the representation of a null pointer be all-bits-zero.  If that does happen to be the (a) null-pointer representation of your implementation, which is common, then `memset(pointer_to_pointers, 0, num_bytes)` does set pointer objects in the space to which `pointer_to_pointers` points to null.  If that is not the (appropriate) null pointer representation, however, then that call *will not* set the pointers to null.

But if your intent is to obtain memory set to all-bits-zero, then how about using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`?  For example,

```
    void** items = calloc(new_len, sizeof(*items));
```

That even relieves you of the need to perform a separate computation of the number of bytes required.

### Main Issue

Running your program under Valgrind reveals leakage of four objects, two allocated directly in function `main` (at lines 16 and 20), and two allocated in `hash_map_add` (both at line 133).

The ones allocated in `main()` are your two `Point` objects.  This is strange because although you do not free those in `main()` your `destroy_hash_map()` function attempts to free them (though the wisdom of this is suspect).

The ones allocated in `hash_map_add()` are the copies of the keys.  These are initially stored in the map, so either they are lost during some manipulation of the map, or they are not freed when the map is destroyed.  Observations:

- the key copies are still lost if I increase the initial capacity of the map so that `resize_hash_map()` is never called, so the problem seems not to be there.
- If I comment out the call to `destroy_hash_map()` then instead of reporting the keys as "definitely lost", is says that they are "indirectly lost", which tells me that the map continues to hold pointers to those keys until it is destroyed, but fails to free them during its destruction.

That got me looking at `destroy_hash_map()`, and after a bit of study I realized that the problem is here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
```

The map always has more buckets than `map->size`, and the buckets in use are not necessarily the first ones.  You need to loop over all `map->capacity` buckets to free the keys (and the items, if that's *really* what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

You're not freeing all memory.

Every pointer returned by `malloc` must eventually be freed with `free`.

Add this:

```
void* MALLOC(size_t size)
{
  void* p = malloc(size);
  printf("MALLOC: %p\n", (void*)p);
  return p;
}

void FREE(void *p)
{
  free(p);
  printf("FREE:   %p\n", (void*)p);
}
```

and replace `malloc` with `MALLOC` and `free` with `FREE`.

The output will be something like this:

```
MALLOC: 0000014FD02CA5D0
MALLOC: 0000014FD02CA890
MALLOC: 0000014FD02CA070
MALLOC: 0000014FD02C6F30   // not freed
MALLOC: 0000014FD02C6F50   // not freed
MALLOC: 0000014FD02C40B0   // not freed
resizing hash map
MALLOC: 0000014FD02C5AF0
MALLOC: 0000014FD02CFF30
FREE:   0000014FD02CA890
FREE:   0000014FD02CA5D0
MALLOC: 0000014FD02C40D0
Point: (1, 2)
Point: (3, 4)
FREE:   0000014FD02C5AF0
FREE:   0000014FD02CFF30
FREE:   0000014FD02CA070
```

(The `// not freed` comments are not part of the output, it's only for illustration).

You can see that there are definitely more `MALLOC`s than `FREE`s. More specicically the addresses with the `// not freed` comment are never freed.

The problem is most likely in `hash_map_add`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am aware that something is not being freed in resize_hash_map, it's a question of what is causing it.